# Why Wildfly does not find the postgresql driver

Tags: java, postgresql, wildfly

I am developping a multi-tier software using java. The middle tier is a java ejb accessing the postgresql database. But when I run the client java application, I have the following error messages:

```
INFO: EJBCLIENT000069: Using legacy jboss-ejb-client.properties security configuration
Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBException: WFLYEJB0442: Unexpected Error
....
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/postgresql/Driver
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
```

The content of the module.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.postgresql">
<resources>
<!--the name of your driver -->
<resource-root path="postgresql-42.2.6.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

The following lines have been added to the standalone.xml file:

```
<driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
<driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
<xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource- 
class>
</driver>
```

The driver and the module.xml are in folder \modules\org\postgresql\main. I have successfully tested my code by moving it to a single-tier java application. I am using Eclipse jee latest verion, wildfly 16, postgresql 11. the driver is postgresql-42.2.6.jar

I have already spent several days battling with the problem, but no success. Help most welcome.

```
package loginPackage;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import org.postgresql.Driver;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class LoginDao {
    static String errorMessage;
    static String connectionResult;

    public static String getConnectionResult() {
        return connectionResult;
    }

    public static void setConnectionResult(String connectResult) {
        connectionResult = connectResult;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public static void setErrorMessage(String errorMsg) {
        errorMessage = errorMsg;
    }
    public static void LoginCheck(String userCode, String userPswd) {

        setConnectionResult(userConnect(userCode, userPswd));


    }

    public static  String userConnect(String userCode, String userPaswd) {

            try {
                //Connection conn = null;
                setConnectionResult("OK");
                setErrorMessage("OK");
                Driver driver = new org.postgresql.Driver();
                DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);

                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/TestDb", userCode, userPaswd);

                System.out.println("Connected to PostgreSQL database!");
                return "SUCCESS";    
            }  

            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to create JDBC db connection " + e.toString() + e.getMessage());
                setErrorMessage(userCode + ", " + userPaswd + ", " + e.toString() + ", " + e.getMessage() + ", " + e.getStackTrace());
                return "FAILURE" ;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your configuration seems correct. Please ensure that you are actually using configured `standalone.xml` when starting the application server.

Comment: leopal, thank you for your answer. I renames standalone.xml, wildfly could not be started. I renamed module.xml and had following error message:

Comment: 0:08:06,847 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "postgresql")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0115: Module for driver [org.postgresql] or one of it dependencies is missing: [org.postgresql]"
10:08:06,848 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "org.postgresql")
])

Comment: Can you try removing line `<driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>` from `module.xml`?

Comment: I removed the line (not from module.xml) from standalone.xml and had the same error message

Comment: I edited my post by adding the java code. based on the trace returned, the error occurs on line Driver driver = new org.postgresql.Driver();

Comment: Do you have a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` that adds the `org.postgresql` module to your deployment?

Comment: @James, thank you for your answer. I don't have a jboss-deployment-structure file. How should it be built and where should I put it ?

Comment: @James, thank you so much, after 10 days battling, your answer is the solution. I placed the file in folder ejbModule\Meta-Inf. Its content is:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
      <dependencies>
         <module name="org.postgresql"/>
      </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>